# MySQL inner joins?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a database design for a survey.

I have a Table USERS with user_id PK and name.

QUESTION with question_id and question_text.

POSSIBLE_ANSWER with answer_id PK ,value, text.

Also, I have USER_ANSWERS with user_id from users , Question_id , answer_id .

Also some 3 other tables not relevant to my question.

What I need is select avg(value) for all users where name like'm%'.

Hope this is clear thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
select avg(PA.value)
from POSSIBLE_ANSWER PA
inner join USER_ANSWERS UA on PA.answer_id = UA.answer_id
inner join USERS U on U.user_id = UA.user_id 
where U.name like 'm%'
```

Comment: @Crontab: Depending on the database, it might not necessarily be true. If no GROUP BY is specified, at least MySQL creates an implicit group of all rows in the result-set

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand: true, I was assuming the asker wanted the averages for each user like you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @Crontab not every time aggregate functions need group by, if we have multiple columns in select list with a aggregate function, then group by is necessary, in this case we don't need it.

Comment: question is to get the avg for all the users with name starting with 'm'

Comment: @Vikram: The statement "avg for all the users with name starting with 'm'" can be interpreted in multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, AVG(pa.value) 
FROM USER_ANSWERS ua 
INNER JOIN POSSIBLE_ANSWER pa ON pa.answer_id = ua.answer_id
INNER JOIN USERS u ON ua.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.name LIKE 'm%'
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Remove `GROUP BY` if you want the average of all users with name starting with 'm'. This query gives the average PER user, whose name starts with m.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
SELECT u.name, AVG(pa.value) AS avgvalue
FROM USER_ANSWERS ua
INNER JOIN USERS u ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
INNER JOIN POSSIBLE_ANSWER pa ON pa.answer_id = ua.answer_id
WHERE u.name LIKE 'm%'
GROUP BY u.name
```

Though I'm still interested in reading what you have tried so far.  And you could add `u.user_id` to your select list and group by that instead (like PatrikAkerstrand did) - which you'd have to do if your names aren't unique